# Getting values from the source page using "PreviousPage"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I’ve tried to post values between 2 web forms using the PreviousPage technique.
I have followed the MSDN article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx ) about the PreviousPage and I have referred this (http://www.deliciousdotnet.com/2011/03/getting-values-from-source-page-using.html#.Uw7jCvmSz3Q ) as well. All seem to be in order but I am seeing the following "Unknown member 'Designation' of System.Web.UI.Page" about my public methods in the destination page.

What have I done wrong?? Please help. Thank you.

this is my source pages html code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="adduser.aspx.cs" Inherits="adduser" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="../Styles/main_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="min-height: 600px; background-image: none !important;">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1" />
    <div class="lightboxContainer">
        <div class="lightboxContainerSection">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <table cellpadding="5" width="600px" class="style1" style="font-size: 12px; margin: 5px;
                        font-weight: bold;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Find User
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="textbox1" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged">
                                </telerik:RadTextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="RadTextBox1"
                                    ErrorMessage="*" Style="color: #FF0000" ValidationGroup="textbox1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton1" runat="server" Text="Find User" OnClick="RadButton1_Click"
                                    ValidationGroup="textbox1">
                                </telerik:RadButton>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="4">
                                <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid_User" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid_User_NeedDataSource"
                                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadGrid_User_SelectedIndexChanged" AllowPaging="True"
                                    CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None">
                                    <ClientSettings EnablePostBackOnRowClick="True">
                                        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />
                                    </ClientSettings>
                                </telerik:RadGrid>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                User name
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="LabelUser" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Company
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="LabelCompany" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Designation
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="LabelDesignation" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Department
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="LabelDepartment" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Mobile
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="LabelMobile" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="4">
                                <asp:Label ID="LabelConfirmation" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton2" runat="server" onclick="RadButton2_Click" 
                                    Text="Yes">
                                </telerik:RadButton>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
        <hr />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my source page code behind file

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Telerik.Web.UI;

public partial class adduser : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private ActiveDirectory ad = new ActiveDirectory();
    private DatabaseConnect db = new DatabaseConnect();

    public void RadGrid_User_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridDataItem selectedItem = (GridDataItem)RadGrid_User.SelectedItems[0];
        string user = selectedItem["Email"].Text;

        Session["userID"] = user.Split('@')[0];

        RadTextBox1.Text = (string)Session["userID"];

        string detail = ad.GetUserDetails(RadTextBox1.Text.Trim());
        string[] details = detail.Split('/');

        LabelUser.Text = details[0];
        LabelCompany.Text = details[1];
        LabelDepartment.Text = details[3];
        LabelDesignation.Text = details[4];
        LabelMobile.Text = details[5];

        LabelConfirmation.Text = "Do you want to grant "+details[0]+" permission to access the CRI ?";

        LabelUser.Visible = true;
        LabelCompany.Visible = true;
        LabelDepartment.Visible = true;
        LabelDesignation.Visible = true;
        LabelMobile.Visible = true;
        LabelConfirmation.Visible = true;
        RadButton2.Visible = true;
    }

    public void RadGrid_User_NeedDataSource(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        string username = this.RadTextBox1.Text.Trim();
        if (username.Length >= 1)
        {
            this.RadGrid_User.DataSource = this.ad.GetUserDetails_WildCard(this.RadTextBox1.Text.Trim());
        }
        else
        {
            this.RadGrid_User.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.db.IsAllowedAdministrator(this.User.Identity.Name))
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                LabelCompany.Visible = false;
                LabelDepartment.Visible = false;
                LabelDesignation.Visible = false;
                LabelMobile.Visible = false;
                LabelUser.Visible = false;
                LabelConfirmation.Visible = false;
                RadButton2.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.Response.Redirect("~/ZCRI_RestrictedAdmin.aspx");
        }
    }

    protected void RadButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.RadGrid_User.Rebind();
        this.RadGrid_User.Visible = true;
    }
    protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LabelCompany.Visible = false;
        LabelDepartment.Visible = false;
        LabelDesignation.Visible = false;
        LabelMobile.Visible = false;
        LabelUser.Visible = false;
        LabelConfirmation.Visible = false;
        RadButton2.Visible = false;
    }

    public string Designation
    {
        get
        {
            return LabelDesignation.Text;
        }
    }

    public string Mobile
    {
        get
        {
            return LabelMobile.Text;
        }
    }

    public string Company
    {
        get
        {
            return LabelCompany.Text;
        }
    }

    public string Department
    {
        get
        {
            return LabelDepartment.Text;
        }
    }
    protected void RadButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect(@"~/AdminInterfaces\adduserpermission.aspx");
    }
}
```

This is my destination page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="adduserpermission.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="adduserpermission" %>
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/AdminInterfaces/adduser.aspx" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="../Styles/main_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="min-height: 600px; background-image: none !important;">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1" />
    <div class="lightboxContainer">
        <div class="lightboxContainerSection">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="Label2"
                runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="Label3"
                runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="Label4"
                runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My destination page code behind file

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public partial class adduserpermission : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = PreviousPage.Designation;
        Label2.Text = PreviousPage.Department;
        Label3.Text = PreviousPage.Company;
        Label4.Text = PreviousPage.Mobile;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now this will work as i confused labels with your properties.

On previous Page you have a label with name `LabelDesignation` but here you are using wrong name to access it. try to use this.

You have an issue with this code in source page code behind file

```
this.Response.Redirect("~/ZCRI_RestrictedAdmin.aspx");
```

The PreviousPage property returns the page that sent control to this page using Server.Transfer.

If the current page is being rendered as a result of a direct request (not a transfer or cross-post from another page), the PreviousPage property contains null.

```
    else
    {
        this.Server.Transfer("~/ZCRI_RestrictedAdmin.aspx");
    }



using System;
using System.Linq;

public partial class adduserpermission : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (Page.PreviousPage != null)
       {
         if(Page.PreviousPage.IsCrossPagePostBack == true)
         {
            Label1.Text = PreviousPage.Designation;
            Label2.Text = PreviousPage.Department;
            Label3.Text = PreviousPage.Company;
            Label4.Text = PreviousPage.Mobile;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to cast it to right type:

```
public partial class adduserpermission : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        adduser prevPage = PreviousPage as adduser;
        if (prevPage != null)
        {
            Label1.Text = prevPage.Designation;
            Label2.Text = prevPage.Department;
            Label3.Text = prevPage.Company;
            Label4.Text = prevPage.Mobile;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And btw try using proper naming conventions on class names too :)

Comment: rest of the things are OK but he/she is using wrong variable names in destination page.

Comment: she tries to access the properties with these names (which _do_ exist in the adduser page). my code shows how.

Comment: On Previous page she has only Designation, Department, Company, Mobile  as text in columns which is not accessible. Look at code you have posted above she is accessing Mobile and assigning it to Label4 which means she is accessing label from previous page.

Comment: @Lev I tried what you suggested and it gave me this error... Error 'adduser' does not contain a definition for 'Designation' and no extension method 'Designation' accepting a first argument of type 'adduser' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: @Lev You are absolutely Right but still your code is wrong.

Comment: and i just tried @AftabAhmed code too still it gives me the same error.

Comment: @Gayanee try again i have edited it now it will work.

Comment: I changed my public methods to the following,  public string GetDesignation
    {
        get
        {
            return LabelDesignation.Text;
        }
    }

    public string GetMobile
    {
        get
        {
            return LabelMobile.Text;
        }
    }

    public string GetCompany
    {
        get
        {
            return LabelCompany.Text;
        }
    }

    public string GetDepartment
    {
        get
        {
            return LabelDepartment.Text;
        }
    }

Comment: Page.PreviousPage returns null @AftabAhmed

Comment: Your issue is fixed try to fix the line in source page code behind file as mentioned in my answer below